# Question on basic functions?

Tags: functions

I was having trouble with this question:

"If $f(x+3) = (x-1)^2 + 4$, find $f(a-1)$

I think this is simple, but I've completely forgotten what to do. :P
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(a-1)=f((a-4)+3):=((a-4)-1)^2+4\;\ldots\ldots$$

Comment: If it also asked to Evaluate f(4), would I just let x=1 so that the left side of the equation becomes: f(1+3)?

Comment: Indeed so, @missiledragon . Nice.